# ASP.NET MVC = a lot of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need your advice. I'm writing an application ASP.NET MVC + jQuery + jQuery UI that's work great but there is a lot of jQuery in a page, it's like 10 years ago with javascript (except jquery is easier). In a view (not all), I have around 50% of HTML (TextBoxFor and other ....) and 50% of jQuery.

Do you have the same feeling ?  I do something wrong ?

Thanks,

Comment: huh? im not sure what you mean? jQuery did not exist 10 years ago....

Comment: Im not really sure what you're asking here...

Comment: depending on what you're doing there can still be a lot of javascript written even if you are using jquery.

Comment: They didn't state that jQuery DID exist 10 years ago, they stated it's LIKE 10 years ago WITH JavaScript, except NOW using jQuery is easier.  Meaning 10 years ago, when your projects used a TON of JS. It seems that the OP feels that went away with the advent of ASP.NET handling everything, but now it seems that with the advent of jQuery, it's back to a TON of JS.

Comment: maybe if you post some code from your views, we could answer you more concretely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, but mainly because today's sites are a lot more interactive than they were 10 years ago, with AJAX etc.

There's no getting away from client-side code if you want a dynamic interface. The WebForms style (with ASP.NET AJAX) abstracted a lot of it away, but at a cost in terms of flexibility and performance (and a bunch of server-side code clutter instead).

One of the reasons I love MVC is that it forces developers to think with clarity about what they are doing at the server side and client side separately.

If you are having trouble decluttering your MVC Views, consider putting the script in separate include files. However, I understand that often your script is necessarily in the View because it's got a bunch of inline MVC code with Model references in it e.g. `$.ajax({url: '<%: Url.Action(Model.DeleteCalendarPageName) %>'});`

Alternatively, if you have a lot of functions on the page, group them into separate script blocks so you can use VS outlining to open and close them for convenience e.g.

```
<script id="scriptStartupCode" type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
<script id="scriptBasketFunctions" type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
<script id="scriptAjaxFunctions" type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
```

Comment: Downvoted? Why. The OP said he was using jQuery - therefore there is gonna be jQuery in his code somewhere. He was wondering if MVC goes hand in hand with lots of javascript: in my experience, yes. If that wasn't the case, the MVC team wouldn't have pressed so hard to get jQuery support built into VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to implement an MVC application. The amount of jQuery is related to what you need to do, so if you have a lot of JavaScript functionality it is going to be there. I have written MVC apps that have a lot of JavaScript/jQuery and ones that have nearly zero.

Comment: your are right, but ASP.NET MVC without jQuery (or other) give very basic UI

Answer (score 0):

Keep your Javascript in a separate file and reference it from your markup.  In this day and age, there is no reason to have any Javascript artefacts in your markup proper.  If you need to set up events, you can do so with css selectors.

There's nothing inherently wrong with markup having a lot of Javascript associated with it.  If you need it, you need it.  However, there are ways to keep your markup maintainable.  Separating concerns should be your first step.

Answer (score 0):

### You don't have to but it's usually a much richer experience

If you write usual page postback applications there's no particular need for writing extensive Javascript. But these days browsers evolved exactly for the purpose of creating more interactive and better experience applications and javascript is their language thus we have to write more of it. But as said **we don't have to if we want to have applications that work as 10 years old applications**.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong if you're using lots of JavaScript to achieve the level of interactivity that Google's Gmail or other similar websites offers.  High interactivity is what people expect these days.  My recent Classic ASP and MVC apps uses more JavaScript compared to the apps I made a few years ago. In the past, having to write custom JavaScript specific to IE5 or Netscape was a chore.  Today, all browsers' JavaScript engines are way faster and jQuery makes writing JS easier.

If you want to keep your Views clean, extract all your JavaScript from your Views and store them in a .js file.  I usually make a JS function like "**LoadMyPage(var1, var2)**" which initializes all html elements' click events (using jQuery) and any other JavaScript stuff.  Then all I have to do is add "**`<script type="text/JavaScript">$(function () {LoadMyPage('var1', 'var2');});</script>`**" to my view.  That one line may call a page worth of JavaScript code.  Any server-side generated parameter value that's needed in my JavaScript code will be passed as parameters which in this case are "var1" and "var2".